# How to infinite loop inside function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm having problem to make code (I'm still learning) that will comunicate with MQTT server and check actual status of GPIO pin that I can control using local web page.

My issue is that I don't know how to make infinite loop inside function that will check actual state of pin and compare it with last state sent by MQTT and if there was change it will publish new value to MQTT.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import urllib
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


#Conf GPIO Number for relays
out_1 = 6

#Conf MQTT broker
broker_ip = "192.168.1.34"
broker_port = 1883
broker_timeout = 60
topic_sub = "/printer/#"
topic_out1 = "/printer/onoff"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(out_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.HIGH)

def main():
    # This is the issue part where I wanted to make looped check for actual value
    def check_state(astate):
            f= open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio6/value","r")
            if f.mode == "r":
                    state = f.read(1)
            if astate == state :
                    return
            else:
                    print("CHANGE")

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
            client.subscribe(topic_sub)

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            if msg.topic == topic_out1 :
                    if msg.payload == "1" :
                            GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.LOW)
                            state = "1"
                            sleep(.1)
                            print("OUT 1 ON")
                    if msg.payload == "0" :
                            GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.HIGH)
                            state = "0"
                            sleep(.1)
                            print("OUT 1 OFF")

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect(broker_ip, broker_port, broker_timeout)

    client.loop_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
            main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()
```

EDIT: 
This is how I made it after help from @MilkyWay90 with multiprocessing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import urllib
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


#Conf GPIO Number for relays
out_1 = 6

#Conf MQTT broker
broker_ip = "192.168.1.34"
broker_port = 1883
broker_timeout = 60
topic_sub = "/printer/#"
topic_out1 = "/printer/onoff"

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(out_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.HIGH)

def check_state():
        import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
        clientSEND = mqtt.Client()
        clientSEND.connect(broker_ip, broker_port, broker_timeout)
        while True:
                faf= open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio6/value","r")
                qf= open("/home/pi/.state","r")
                fastate = faf.read(1)
                #reverse logic for gpio value
                if fastate == "0" :
                        astate = "1"
                elif fastate == "1" :
                        astate = "0"
                qstate = qf.read(1)
                #print("GPIO state: ",astate,"MQTT state: ",qstate)
                if astate != qstate :
                        clientSEND.publish(topic_out1, astate)
                        #print("CHANGE")
                        sleep(3)
                else:
                        sleep(3)

def mqtt():
        import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
        def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
                client.subscribe(topic_sub)

        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
                if msg.topic == topic_out1 :
                        if msg.payload == "1" :
                                GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.LOW)
                                state_write("1")
                                sleep(.1)
                                #print("OUT 1 ON")
                        if msg.payload == "0" :
                                GPIO.output(out_1, GPIO.HIGH)
                                state_write("0")
                                sleep(.1)
                                #print("OUT 1 OFF")

        def state_write(state):
                f= open("/home/pi/.state","w")
                f.write(state)
                f.close

        client = mqtt.Client()
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.on_message = on_message

        client.connect(broker_ip, broker_port, broker_timeout)

        client.loop_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
                bck_statuscheck = Process(target=check_state)
                mqtt_process = Process(target=mqtt)
                bck_statuscheck.start()
                mqtt_process.start()
                bck_statuscheck.join()
                mqtt_process.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but `while True` is an infinite loop. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [while loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm).

A while loop is a loop in Python which runs the specified code while the condition evaluates to [True](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/boolean).

This is the structure of a while loop:

```
while <condition>:
    CODE
```

An example could be:

```
counter = 1 # Declare a variable named "counter" and set it to the integer 1
while counter <= 10: # This is the while loop. As you can see, the condition checks whether the counter is less than or equal to the integer 10. If it is, execute the code that is indented. This will be checked every iteration
    print(counter) # Use the print function to print out the counter with a newline
    counter += 1 # Increment the counter. This is roughly equivalent to counter = counter + 1
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9YtqCyo/P8/Ob80ryS1SMFWwZCrPCMzJ1UBJmIDFDKw4uIsKMrMK9GAimpyccLktYHy//8DAA)

You can trivially modify the while statement to ALWAYS evalulate to True:

```
counter = 1
while True:
   print(counter)
   counter += 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9YtqCyo/P8/Ob80ryS1SMFWwZCrPCMzJ1UhpKg01YqLs6AoM69EAyqtycUJU6gNVPn/PwA)

This does work in a function.

```
def print_natural_numbers():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print(counter)
        counter += 1

print_natural_numbers()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9YtqCyo/P8/JTVNoaAoM68kPi@xpLQoMSc@rzQ3KbWoWEPTioszOb80ryS1SMFWwZCLszwjMydVIaSoNBUowwnWpAFVoAkUgKnVBinmwmHm//8A)

To modify the above to your needs:

```
def check_state(astate):
        while True:
                f= open("/sys/class/gpio/gpio6/value","r")
                if f.mode == "r":
                        state = f.read(1)
                if astate == state :
                        return
                else:
                        print("CHANGE")
```

Or for an alternative:

```
while True:
    check_state(...)
```

**EDIT:**

> wouldn't be after this stucked in one function whole time? so it will check only actual state but ignore everithing else (MQTT part)?

(Rephrased: With the above code, this would run this the entire time (because of the while loop) and not continue on to the other code)

Looks like this requires [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html).

A demonstration:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_natural_numbers():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print(counter, flush = True)
        counter += 1

def print_square_numbers():
    counter = 1
    while True:
        print(counter ** 2, flush = True)
        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nat_numbers = Process(target=print_natural_numbers)
    sqrt_numbers = Process(target=print_square_numbers)
    sqrt_numbers.start()
    nat_numbers.start()
    sqrt_numbers.join()
    nat_numbers.join()
```

For your case, you would need to make two functions: the checking function and the function that represents everything else.

Comment: wouldn't be after this stucked in one function whole time? so it will check only actual state but ignore everithing else (MQTT part)?

Comment: @MartinRehak I can edit in a multiprocessing option

Comment: @MartinRehak Okay, I edited it. If this helps you, remember to click the accept button so other people know that this solution works.

Comment: @MartinRehak You also may want to consider putting in a `sleep` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to change `client.loop_forever()` to `client.start_loop()` ([docs](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#loop-start-loop-stop)).

This will start the MQTT client loop on it's own thread in the background and then you can add your own `while True:` loop to the `main` function after you start the loop e.g.

```
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(broker_ip, broker_port, broker_timeout)

client.start_loop()

while True:
   check_state()
   sleep(1)
```

(p.s. You really shouldn't be sleeping in the `on_message` callback as this happens on the network thread and slows down message handling)